# How to store html in database consumed by android REST web service?

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, rest

I'm currently creating an android app, with java rest web service and database.

I'm quite a newbie when it comes to both android and web service development, I was just wondering if anyone could give me any tips.

I'm wanting to create a new feed within the app, similar to the facebook or sky sports. The source will be small html articles and displayed using listview; I was just wondering the best way to store the html files. The web service isn't consuming a website, instead they are just individual files.

I thought about storing them in the database and connecting that to the web service, is that a good idea? if so how would you store them correctly in a database? I want it stored as html instead of plain text due to formatting needs.

The rest of the data stored in the database will be consumed by the web service, however this will be just parsed using json.

If anyone has any tips or links that would be great, I havent been able to find any relevant information or examples.

much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There's a great SQLite Database article [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) -- Hope this helps!

And as for how to store it, I think parsing, as you've suggested, is a good idea -- and storing the structured information rather than just as plain text.